# How do I type a ref callback with useCallback with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to Typescript and can't figure out how to type this situation.
I'm writing a custom hook and trying to create a callback ref.
My problem is that this function sets the ref's `current`, and returns nothing, but since I use it as a ref, typescript yells at me `Property 'current' is missing in type '(node: any) => void' but required in type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'`.

Thank you in advance.

This is the code:

```
import React, {useCallback, useRef} from 'react'

const useCustom = (): [RefObject<HTMLDivElement>] => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
  const setRef = useCallback(node => {
    ....
    ref.current = node
  }, [])

  return [setRef]
}

const SomeComp = () => {
  const [ref] = useCustom()

  return <div ref={ref}>Text</div>
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you said the return value of `useCustom` would be `RefObject<HTMLDivElement>`, but returned `(node: HTMLDivElement) => void`.

Your custom hook should return 2 values: one for setting the ref value, the other for the ref itself. So it will look like `useState` hook:

```
const useCustom = (): [
  RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
  (node: HTMLDivElement) => void
] => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const setRef = useCallback((node) => {
    ref.current = node;
  }, []);

  return [ref, setRef];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose a different solution.

This is assuming the author is trying to use a "callback ref" to execute a side effect, when the ref changes. When using two return values the ref might still accidentally be set (by using the `ref`) without executing the callback (`setRef`), which I'm guessing is not the author's intention.

Typing things like this seems to work as expected (using author's example):

```js
import React, {useCallback, useRef} from 'react'

const useCustom = (): [React.RefCallback<HTMLElement>] => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null)
    const setRef: React.RefCallback<HTMLElement> = useCallback(node => {
    ....
    ref.current = node
  }, [])

  return [setRef]
}

const SomeComp = () => {
  const [ref] = useCustom()

  return <div ref={ref}>Text</div>
}
```

Note: I also changed `HTMLDivElement` to `HTMLElement` to make the hook more universal.

Comment: Why do you put the refcallback in an array as the hook return value `useCustom = (): [React.RefCallback<HTMLElement>]` , then pluck it out of the array on the calling side `[ref] = useCustom()`  ?